# CentOS 6 ClamAV scan unexpected results

Tags: centos6, clamav

I am trying to scan whole server with below command using clamav. However I already installed Malware detector. The server scans for upto a minute or two and found some unexpected scanning results where I am unable to find any solution while googling.

> clamscan -r /

Below is the result

```
/proc/43/task/43/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/43/task/43/root: Symbolic link
/proc/43/task/43/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/43/task/43/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/task/43/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/43/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/43/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/43/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/43/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/43/net/ip6_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip6_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip6_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/nf_conntrack_expect: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/packet: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/unix: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/snmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/netstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/sockstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/icmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/udp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/tcp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/raw: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip_mr_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ip_mr_vif: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/udplite: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/mcfilter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/igmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/xfrm_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/rt_acct: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/route: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/arp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/psched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/dev_mcast: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/wireless: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/ptype: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/softnet_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/dev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/protocols: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/connector: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/netlink: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/netfilter/nf_log: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/netfilter/nf_queue: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/stat/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/stat/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/net/stat/arp_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/autogroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/43/root: Symbolic link
/proc/43/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/43/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/mountstats: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/coredump_filter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/43/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/root: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/44/task/44/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/task/44/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/44/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/44/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/44/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/44/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/44/net/ip6_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip6_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip6_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/nf_conntrack_expect: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/packet: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/unix: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/snmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/netstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/sockstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/icmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/udp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/tcp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/raw: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip_mr_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ip_mr_vif: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/udplite: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/mcfilter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/igmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/xfrm_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/rt_acct: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/route: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/arp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/psched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/dev_mcast: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/wireless: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/ptype: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/softnet_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/dev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/protocols: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/connector: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/netlink: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/netfilter/nf_log: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/netfilter/nf_queue: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/stat/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/stat/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/net/stat/arp_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/autogroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/44/root: Symbolic link
/proc/44/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/44/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/mountstats: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/coredump_filter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/44/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/root: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/45/task/45/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/task/45/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/45/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/45/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/45/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/45/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/45/net/ip6_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip6_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip6_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/nf_conntrack_expect: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/packet: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/unix: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/snmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/netstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/sockstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/icmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/udp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/tcp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/raw: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip_mr_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ip_mr_vif: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/udplite: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/mcfilter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/igmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/xfrm_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/rt_acct: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/route: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/arp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/psched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/dev_mcast: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/wireless: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/ptype: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/softnet_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/dev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/protocols: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/connector: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/netlink: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/netfilter/nf_log: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/netfilter/nf_queue: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/stat/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/stat/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/net/stat/arp_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/autogroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/45/root: Symbolic link
/proc/45/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/45/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/mountstats: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/coredump_filter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/45/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/root: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/46/task/46/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/task/46/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/46/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/46/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/46/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/46/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/46/net/ip6_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip6_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip6_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/nf_conntrack_expect: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/packet: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/unix: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/snmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/netstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/sockstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/icmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/udp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/tcp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/raw: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip_mr_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ip_mr_vif: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/udplite: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/mcfilter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/igmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/xfrm_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/rt_acct: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/route: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/arp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/psched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/dev_mcast: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/wireless: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/ptype: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/softnet_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/dev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/protocols: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/connector: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/netlink: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/netfilter/nf_log: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/netfilter/nf_queue: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/stat/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/stat/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/net/stat/arp_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/autogroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/46/root: Symbolic link
/proc/46/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/46/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/mountstats: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/coredump_filter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/46/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/status: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/personality: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/limits: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/sched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/comm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/syscall: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/cmdline: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/statm: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/numa_maps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/mem: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/cwd: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/root: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/exe: Symbolic link
/proc/47/task/47/mounts: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/mountinfo: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/clear_refs: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/smaps: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/pagemap: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/current: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/prev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/exec: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/fscreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/keycreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/attr/sockcreate: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/wchan: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/stack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/schedstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/cpuset: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/cgroup: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/oom_score: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/oom_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/oom_score_adj: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/loginuid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/sessionid: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/task/47/io: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/ns/net: Symbolic link
/proc/47/ns/uts: Symbolic link
/proc/47/ns/ipc: Symbolic link
/proc/47/ns/mnt: Symbolic link
/proc/47/ns/pid: Symbolic link
/proc/47/net/ip6_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip6_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip6_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/nf_conntrack_expect: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip_tables_targets: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip_tables_matches: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip_tables_names: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/packet: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/unix: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/snmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/netstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/sockstat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/icmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/udp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/tcp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/raw: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip_mr_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ip_mr_vif: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/udplite: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/mcfilter: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/igmp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/xfrm_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/rt_acct: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/route: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/arp: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/psched: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/dev_mcast: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/wireless: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/ptype: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/softnet_stat: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/dev: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/protocols: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/connector: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/netlink: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/netfilter/nf_log: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/netfilter/nf_queue: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/stat/nf_conntrack: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/stat/rt_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/net/stat/arp_cache: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/environ: Excluded (/proc)
/proc/47/auxv: Excluded (/proc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are scanning all files on the system. That includes /proc, which contains your own system memory and configuration. ClamAV is telling you that is is excluding those files. Actually I am surprised you don't have more than this, I would have expected files in /dev and /sys to be excluded also.

Comment: Thank you. I used clamscan -r /home to scan all web files and it worked.